# Browser session get expired during script execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Website session get expired during script execution. I have 4 classes which have 15-16 test methods. while i do execute all as a suite using  from testing.xml.

Scenario : Perform search after user Login

I'm using below Condition

```
if(check user is already login)
{
    if(check user is on homepage URL)
    {
       // if user is already on homepage then perform search
    }
    else
    {
        //here my code is  first navigate the page to homepage and then perform search. 
        But the session get destroy once it navigate to home page here and the test get failed as 
    }
}
else
{
   // not login then first do login and then perform search
}
```

So my question are :

1. Is it my website issue or webdriver issue ?
2. Why session getting logout on page navigation ? I have tried both `driver.get()` and `driver.navigate().to()` but no success.

Can someone give me the clue if such problem has been faced ?

Comment: Thats proabably how your web services might be maintaining the session.

Comment: You need to check why the session is breaking, it may be your website issue or it may be that it was designed to do that for some reason. So figure that out first yourself

Comment: You haven't provide an [mcve] where we can repro the issue.

Comment: @JeffC, The code  is same as i mentioned  condition. If i post the same then it also show the same things (nothing more then this ) that's why i haven't added. Although your answer is helpful other then managing redundancy of code and so much condition. It helps me to do the same in 3 steps +1 for that. Still I'm getting the user logout issue meanwhile the test execution.

Comment: You haven't posted the relevant code that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it's hard to tell what actual problem is but you do have a logic/[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) issue. From the comments in your code, you have your search code in 3 different places. A better logic flow would be something like this

```
if (user is not logged in)
{
     // log in
}
if (browser is not on homepage URL)
{
    // navigate to home page
}
// now you can do the search
```

Part of the issue may be that you seem to be reusing sessions. The fact that you need to check whether the user is logged in or on the homepage indicates that you don't know where the test is at any given point.

A better way to write this test is to create a single test that instantiates the browser, navigates to the home page, logs the user in, does the search, and then closes the browser. That's one test. If you need to repeat that test with different search criteria, then you can do data driven testing. Having a small test like this will make it easier to know what the script is doing and less likely to have session timeout, etc. issues.

Comment: @JeffC, I have already done the things whatever you are trying to say